# No compiled executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, directx

I was playing around with DirectX SDK and made a small test app. It has a very high CPU usage on my laptop where I made it and I wanted to try it on my PC. I went to the Debug folder but there was no executable inside the folder only .obj files and .tlog files. I tried running a release compilation but that didn't change the situation - still no executable.

Am I doing something wrong or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong folder.  Do a search starting at the solution level (not project), or else take a closer look at the build output or project properties; both of those contain the real path.

If you're used to one of the other Visual Studio languages, like C#, be aware that C++ uses a different directory structure.

By default

- In C#, the exe is under `$(Project)\bin\Release`.
- In C++, it's under `$(Solution)\Release`

Of course, this can be changed in the project properties to go absolutely anywhere at all.  Inspecting the build log after "Rebuild All" is the surest way to find all the files.

Comment: yeah I found it. It was one level above where I was looking

Answer (score 0):

To find you exact place of the compiled .exe file open the output window on visual studio and after you build it you would see the exact path of the exe